# How to get an input integer (age) to subtract from a set integer (65)and display the results (years till retirement)?

Tags: c#

Ive been working on this console program code for hours and cant figure out how to get it to work.

1. Create a class "person.cs"

   - add three variables with property for each name(string), age(int), YearsToWork(int)
   - method YTK() YearsToWork = 65 - Age;
2. main()

   - enter name
   - enter age
   - show "You will work: __ years before you retire."

Code:

```
class Person
{
    internal int age, yearsToWork;
    internal string name;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = (int)value; }
    }

    public int YearsToWork
    {
        get { return yearsToWork; }
        set { yearsToWork = (int)value; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        string Name;
        int age;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
        Name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age :  ");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");

        Console.WriteLine("You will work : {0} years before you retire.", yearsToWork);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: A small comment: you don't need (and shouldn't) the conversion to `int` in the property `YearsToWork`.

Comment: Your code is incomplete: you define the Person object but you don't use it. You are on the right track but review the basic OOP. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since `YearsToWork` is to be automatically computed, you can simply do this.
You could also add a simple check so you won't have negative years to work.

```
public int YearsToWork =>Age<65  ? 65-Age : 0;
```

As a method:

```
public int YearsToWork() =>Age < 65  ? 65-Age : 0;
```

Your code needs a little refactoring as under:

```
var person = new Person();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
person.Name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age :  ");
person.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine($"You will work : {0} years before you 
retire.", person.YearsToWork());


Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public int YearsToWork
{
    get { return 65 - Age; }
}
```

but you need change this:

```
Name = Console.ReadLine();
```

for this:

```
person.Name = Console.ReadLine();
```

because you are creating an empty person ande never fills its data.

Comment: As a property... But he requested a method `YTK()`.

Comment: It won't work since you don't have an instance of `Person` and no static properties, but instance properties.

Comment: sorry i mean person not Person the class

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `Person` object instead of only variables. Set the name and age of the `Person` after you collect them from the user:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
Name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age :  ");
age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

person.name = Name;
person.age = age;
```

Then you need to change your `YearsToWork` property in your `Person` class to a method to do the calculation like this:

```
public int YearsToWork()
{
    return 65 - this.age;
}
```

Then the last step is to call the method from your `Person` object and print the calculated result:

```
int yearsToWork = person.YearsToWork();

Console.WriteLine("You will work : {0} years before you retire.", yearsToWork);
```

Comment: Your `Console.WriteLine` is incorrect because it doesn't call a method (it looks like it is a property, and not cased right). `YearsToWork` should be a read-only property anyway, not a method.

Comment: @RonBeyer the line right above it stores the method result into a variable. Then the WriteLine calls the variable, not the direct method.

Comment: Either way it should be a property, there is no reason to use a method there (and part of the OP's "requirements" says it needs to be a property anyway).

Comment: @RonBeyer Sure. However, it doesn't make sense to have a property store the value AND a method to calculate it on the fly. OP can change code as they see fit for their specific situation.

Comment: You don't need a method to "calculate it on the fly", just use a read-only property, ie: `public int YearsToWork => 65 - Age;` would be just fine. Or the long-winded way: `public int YearsToWork { get { return 65 - Age; } }`

Comment: @RonBeyer I agree with that. That would be better! However, OP asked for a method to calculate Years to Work.

Comment: So it's still coming back that the term "YearsToWork" already contains a definition.

Comment: @user11545861 you have to remove your property `YearsToWork` or rename the method to something else (like `YTK()`)

Comment: Now it is saying the namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: @user11545861 stick that method inside your `Person` class. Double check your `{ }` to make sure they line up correctly.

Comment: public int YTK (int age)
    {
        {
            int YearsToWork = 65 - Age;
        }
    } Not really sure what Im doing wrong, but it wont work .

Comment: @user11545861 `public int YTK ( ) { return 65 - this.age; }`. Remove the input parameter, remove a set of curly braces, just call return [calculation]

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Program1
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         var person = new Person();
         int yearsTillRetire;

         Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name..")
         person.Name = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age..")
         person.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         yearsTillRetire = YearsToWork(person.Age);

         Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

         Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {1}. Looks like you have {0} years left for work", yearsTillRetire, person.Name);

         Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int Age {get; set;}
    }

    public int YearsToWork (int age)
    {
        if (age < 65) return (65 - age);
        /*you could also probably throw some condition in here to check if 
          they're over 65 as well*/
    }
}
```

I didn't get a chance to test this on my IDE so I don't know if it'll work (in theory it should), .. let me know how it goes! :-)

Looking at this project again, to be honest, you don't even need to create a person class. You coouuld also just create a string variable name and an int variable age. Like so:

```
using System;

namespace Program1
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         string name;
         int age;
         int yearsTillRetire;

         Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name..")
         name = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age..")
         age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         yearsTillRetire = YearsToWork(age);

         Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

         Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {0}. Looks like you have {1} years left for work",  name, yearsTillRetire);

         Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public int YearsToWork (int age)
    {
        if (age < 65) return (65 - age);
        /*you could also probably throw some condition in here to check if 
          they're over 65 as well*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant seem to figure out why this program wont work.

```
{
    class Person
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public int YearsToWork { get; set; }
 }
  public int YTK(int age)
  {
    {
        int YearsToWork = 65 - Age;
    }
  }
}
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var person = new Person();
    int yearsTillRetire;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name : ");
    Person.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age :  ");
    Person.Age = 
    Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    yearsTillRetire = YearsToWork(person.Age);

    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------- 
     --------------");


    Console.WriteLine("You will work : {0} years 
    before you retire.", yearsTillRetire);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```